# What is the $ called That starts in every Linux terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal

I'm really confused is it called a "Dollar" , "Shell" or something else because I want to make a Linux tutorial that involves using terminals and these and I feel kind of shy calling it "The dollar sign"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically what i understand from your question is, you are enquiring about what is known in the unix world as

> Prompt String

It lets you set the look and feel of you shell prompt.

Answer (score 0):

It's the end of the prompt.

- `$` is the normal end of the user command prompt
- `#` is the normal end of the root command prompt

The prompt is the whole string, as far as I know there's no special name
for the last character of the prompt.

Comment: Instead of writing *It's the end of the the prompt...*, I would suggest you to write it as `the last character of the shell prompt`. The former could leave OP confused as per the terminology used. But, finally it is your call.